# iTunes not showing app update description texts

Tags: macos, itunes

I have a very weird problem with iTunes lately. When I go to Apps → Updates, all apps that show up there, don't have an update description text. The app is displayed, its version is displayed, vendor, size, etc., but no text. I tried to clear the cache from within iTunes, but no luck. This is how it looks like:

[image]

I'd appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: What version iTunes?

Comment: Please answer this so everyone knows that it's a bug.

Comment: The problem resolved itself, when Apple updated its App Store.